# How to do core data contents encryption in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, encryption

I want to encrypt all the core data model contents. If you know any suggestion.
please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's work well for me. You can use it.

https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

Hope that helps!

Update broken URL.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for swift samples. if anything you have, please share with me.
Thanks.

Comment: I think it easy to use `objective-c` framework in `swift`.